# Why can't this chrome extension be installed?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a couple very short + simple extensions that I can't install to chrome. I am given the following error about the 'manifest version', so I assume that the problem is that it is outdated, I haven't any experience in chrome extensions/javascript so I couldn't fix them myself as I would normally try to do, these were written for me by a friend a while back.

Could someone let me know how I should correct these files?

Error:

```
The 'manifest_version' key must be present and set to 2 (without quotes). See developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html for details.
```

Extension files:

manifest.json for extension 1:

```
{
"content_scripts": [ {
  "exclude_globs": [  ],
  "include_globs": [ "*slavehack*index2.php\\?page=internet&openFolder=&var3=files&aktie=*&*=*" ],
  "js": [ "script.js" ],
  "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
} ],
"converted_from_user_script": true,
"description": "",
"key": "XKBlE2kyhcJNHGYLuLylZhjFVQV7puTEQbsFuGRcKoY=",
"name": "Slavehack Process Log Protector",
"version": "1.0"
}
```

script.js for extension 1:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Slavehack Process Log Protector
// @include        *slavehack*index2.php?page=internet&openFolder=&var3=files&aktie=*&*=*
// @version                1.0
// ==/UserScript==
var allA = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < allA.length; i++) {
    if ( allA[i].innerHTML.match('Access logfile') ) {
        window.location.href = allA[i].href;
    }
}
```

manifest.json for extension 2:

```
{
  "content_scripts": [ {
  "exclude_globs": [  ],
  "include_globs": [ "*slavehack*index2.php\\?page=internet&var3=&aktie=FP&var2=*&transfer=*&tonumber=*&toip=*" ],
  "js": [ "script.js" ],
  "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
   } ],
   "converted_from_user_script": true,
   "description": "",
   "key": "WxQnzwPDzxXFW/TSZw6dNJJJSyVIXlub/QQGMlVtjbc=",
   "name": "Bank IP Log Crack Remover",
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

script.js for extension 2:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Bank IP Log Crack Remover
// @include        *slavehack*index2.php?page=internet&var3=&aktie=FP&var2=*&transfer=*&tonumber=*&toip=*
// @version                1.0
// ==/UserScript==
var bankip = window.location.href.split('=')[window.location.href.split('=').length - 1]
window.location.href = 'http://www.slavehack.com/index2.php?page=internet&var2='+bankip.replace('#','')+'&var3=crack&var4=';
```

Many thanks for any help

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory... It even contains a link to documentation that features an example on the expected format.

Comment: Yeah, I gave it my best go at trying to correct the files with the info in the docs but I really don't have any experience in JavaScript and I've never worked with browser extensions so I just couldn't do it. Do you think you could help me out? I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory:

> The 'manifest_version' key must be present and set to 2 (without quotes).
>   See [developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html#current-version) for details.

The [referenced documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html#current-version) provides a very clear example at the top of the page:

```
{
  ...,
  "manifest_version": 2,
  ...
}
```

These dots indicate that parts of the [manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html) were omitted for the sake of the example. You have to edit your `manifest.json` file, and insert `"manifest_version": 2` somewhere in the file.

For example, in your case, you can add a line before the `"version"` key and put the `"manifest_version": 2` declaration over there.

```
   ...
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

Note that there's a comma at the end of the line. In the [JSON](http://json.org/) data format, every name/value pair is separated by a comma.

Comment: My apologies, I did in fact try that before I came here for help but it gave me an error message even after I had done so, but I just tried it again and it seems to have worked. I suppose I must have done something wrong the first time. Thanks a lot for your time I appreciate it.

Comment: this worked for me : "manifest_version": 2,
   "version": "1.0"

Answer (score 0):

add in you 'manifest.json':

`'manifest_version': 2`

example:

```
{
    "name": "name your extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "description your building",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action":{
       "default_icon": "icon777.png",
       "popup": "body.html"
    }
 }
```